# What is the voltage across the diodes D1 and D2?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes

Following is the circuit I have been analyzing. Voltage supply at the input is -6V. I have to calculate the voltage across the diodes (D1&D2) or R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flWlQT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Attached is the voltage I have calculated with my understanding. It is -1.4 V. Can anyone verify the calculations. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you've done it correctly. But that makes this a very boring question for Stackexchange.

Comment: Wow .. I was about to write the answer but you are correct :-D

Comment: You can use free simulator tools like LTspice/Falstad to verify your circuit and calculations.

Comment: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: The answer is incorrect - the diodes are connected the wrong way round to conduct. They are reverse biased as shown. Your method of calculation is correct except for that statement that they conduct.

Comment: You need to mark the assumed polarity of all voltages on your circuit diagram. The normal definition of the voltage across a diode would say that a diode will **not** conduct with an applied voltage of -1.4V.